# cat command output not able to store in variable jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins

I am having text file with values

cat url_pdf.txt
https://gorgon.nr-assets.net/image/d8f3e1f4-1478-4b54-b37f-e06a0f0ed49b?format=PDF&width=2000

I am trying to access that url in jenkins pipeline

```
def url
pipeline{
    agent any
    stages{
     stage("Printing file"){
           sh "cat url_pdf.txt"
          }
     stage("Accessing the variable value") {
            steps {
                script {
                    url = sh (script: 'cat url_pdf.txt',returnStdout: true).trim()
                    sh """
                      echo ${url}
                      """
                   }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Expected output** *https://gorgon.nr-assets.net/image/d8f3e1f4-1478-4b54-b37f-e06a0f0ed49b?format=PDF&width=2000*

My Jenkins is showing output as

[image]

How can I get the complete url output in stage-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really a bash question, nothing to do with Jenkins. Try this on the console

```bash
echo a&width=2000
```

It's basically running two commands `echo a` and `width=2000`
Not sure why you need to echo the variable from a `sh` step. You could just

```
url = sh(script: 'cat url_pdf.txt', returnStdout: true).trim()
echo url
```